# Hide the activity from the toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4, toolbox

Is there any way that can hide the activity i created from appearing in the Visual Studio toolbox.

I know the attribute"ToolbosItem(false)" that hide the custom control appearing in the toolbox, and i tried that is not working for the WF4.

Beside that I found the [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595978/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-a-workflow-from-appearing-in-the-toolbox) ,that Will asked on 2011 and Ron replied that will be an enhancement. I wonder is that enhancement been applied right now?

FYI: I am using visual studio 2010 , .NET 4 /WF4.

Comment: Wouldn't simply hiding the activities in the toolbox be enough?

Comment: @shaamaan
ya, I just wanted to hide some abstract base activities I created, so that the users will not able to drop them to the designer. Any clue?

Comment: I meant, manually hiding components in the toolbox (via right-click)... I don't know how to prevent VS from adding activities to the toolbox.

Comment: LOL ic, sorry for misunderstanding.
Because of my activities will be complied as a dll and let other developers to use, so them might not know which activities actually is an abstract type.